# How to share cookies between 2 windows accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, cookies

Is anybody knows how to share cookies between 2 windows users?

I have a Windows 10, where have 2 users: one is admin and second is operator.

Admin is logged in into the system and then goes to the web site, where setup some config. In this config we have some specific value which should be store locally in machine and operator shouldn't know nothing about it. So he is set some kookie { someKey: someValue } and then log out from Windows.

After this operator log in into Windows and open the same website and he should have access to this cookie { someKey: someValue }.

I search around we and found nothing about it. Found only solutions about save to file system, send via tokens and save MAC address with a value into DB. But this is not suitable for me. I know that share cookies and store locally isn't secure, but need to implement that feature.

Web project based on chrome browser, asp.net mvc, angularjs and ms sql for db storage. Is anybody can help me with this issue about cookies?

Comment: What you are asking for is typically a session hijacking (even if you are in the same computer). Not sure stackoverflow accept questions of this kind (hackers)

Comment: Admin and operator are going to use the same machine and browser?

Comment: @JordiRuiz yes, same machine, same OS. Win 10 and google chrome

Comment: @BorHunter like other people is saying, two different windows users don't share cookies. What you could do is the following: An administrator does some kind of action on the website. The server side stores the data in the session or any other mechanism. Then if another user access to the website and this data has been saved by the administrator the server side can send the data to the client using a cookie.

Comment: @JordiRuiz Do you mean chrome session which is runned in a machine? But isn't for 2 win users has 2 sessions?

Comment: No, I mean asp.net session, on the server side.

Comment: @jordiRuiz we can't, because server and client on different machines.

Comment: It does not matter if they are in the same machine or different machines. You store the data in the server and when another client access to the server via a web request you send them the data that the administrator has saved.

Comment: What @JordiRuiz is suggesting is manage one single copy of the cookie server side and send it to all users to simulate a single cookie. In reality there would be N cookies with the same content, one for each client/browser/user. Since the server should send the same cookie to all users and manage the cookie application wide, there should be have the same content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. First, every browser has its own way to store and retrieve cookies. It is impossible to write something that will work for any platform and any version.

Second, there is security. You can't just copy some files and expect this to work. Browser developers aren't stupid to leave such a big security loophole in their software.

You are mixing Windows applications with full control over the system with a web application that only resides within the browser. You should find a better way. You could use a certificate installed on the machine to validate the user, but it seems to me there are better options, like simply logging in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are a browser component that all major browsers locate in user specific directories. **if** you could change it to HTML5 storage API **and** you could setup the storage to a folder both users have access (dunno about this). You could have client side shared data. Most probably, you could not. And certainly not using cookies.

Disclaimer: I havent used storage API

Edit: Just checked. Storage API does store the data un user specific folders, so cannot use it either.

"*In practice, "client-side storage" means data is passed to the browser's storage API, which saves it on the local device in the same area as it stores other user-specific information, e.g. preferences and cache. Beyond saving data, the APIs let you retrieve data, and in some cases, perform searches and batch manipulations.*" Source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/